# PopupWindow overlap the drawer layout. How to solve it..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, popup

Hi i have struct while using PopupWindow in fragment, And i facing one problem. That is popupWindow show properly, but when open navigation drawer popupWindow overlap the navigation drawer.And i attach screen shot and code. please guide me.. Thanks in advance...

[image]

[image]

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history,container,false);
    parameterses=new ArrayList<>();
    myUtill=new MyUtill(getActivity());
    Log.d("Histroy fragment","onCreateView");


    if (parameterses.size()>0){
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter=new RecycleViewHolder(parameterses);
        Log.d("Histroy","Working");
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else {
        myUtill.showToast(getActivity(),"No Entrys");
        PopupWindows(container,inflater);
    }

    return view;
}

private void PopupWindows(ViewGroup container, LayoutInflater inflater){
    try {


        View popupView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, container,false);


        pw =new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pw.showAsDropDown(popupView,50,800);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    pw.dismiss();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

}

Comment: Just use a regular `TextView` instead, in the same `ViewGroup` as the `RecyclerView`, and toggle its visibility depending on the dataset size.

Comment: you can close the drawer in your `PopupWindows` function...and then show the popup.

Comment: @MikeM. ya i done with 'TestView'. But i want to show 'PopupWindow'.

Comment: Why? That `PopupWindow` just looks like a `TextView` anyway, except it's apparently causing problems.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 how to get drawer open or close function into the another fragment it's long process know.. My thought 'ViewGroup' is play with this roll. And no proper solution for **how to declare new 'ViewGroup' instance**.